# Testing whether $httpProvider.interceptors.push() have been called with jasmine in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have found many articles here how to test Angular's config phase and I was able to create my tests against [restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) and [LocalStorageModule](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) module configuration. The only one I cannot solve yet is checking whether the interceptor was added or not. I do not need to test the service because it is a 3rd party stuff, I consider it is already tested - hopefully.

The question is that, how can I spy on $httpProvider.interceptors.push method which is called in configuration phase?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Here is my code:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myapp', [
            // Angular modules
            'ngAnimate',
            'ngRoute',

            // Custom modules
            'myapp.layout',

            // 3rd Party Modules
            'LocalStorageModule',
            'http-auth-interceptor',
            'restangular'
    ])
    .config(function (RestangularProvider) {

        RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://.../services/webapi/');

    })
    .config(function (localStorageServiceProvider) {

        localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('myapp');

    })
    .config(function($httpProvider) {

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorFactory');

    });
})();


'use strict';

describe('myapp configuration', function() {

    var RestangularProvider,
        localStorageServiceProvider,
        $httpProvider;

    //modules
    beforeEach(function () {

        angular.module('myapp.layout', []);
        angular.module('http-auth-interceptor', []);

    });


    //providers
    beforeEach(function () {

        module('restangular', function(_RestangularProvider_) {

            RestangularProvider = _RestangularProvider_;
            spyOn(RestangularProvider, 'setBaseUrl').and.callThrough();
        });

        module('LocalStorageModule', function (_localStorageServiceProvider_) {

            localStorageServiceProvider = _localStorageServiceProvider_;
            spyOn(localStorageServiceProvider, 'setPrefix').and.callThrough();

        });

        module('myapp', function(_$httpProvider_) {

            $httpProvider = _$httpProvider_;
            spyOn($httpProvider.interceptors, 'push').and.callThrough();

        });

        //module('myapp');

        inject();

    });

    describe('Restangular configuration', function() {

        it('setBaseUrl is set up', function() {

            expect(RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();

        });

    });

    describe('localStorage configuration', function() {

        it('setPrefix is set up', function () {

            expect(localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix).toHaveBeenCalled();

        });

    });

    describe('$httpProvider configuration', function() {

        it('an interceptor is added', function() {

            expect($httpProvider.interceptors.push).toHaveBeenCalled();

        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just been doing this myself and its actually surprisingly easy. Below are two ways you can do this, the first is the way I would recommend.

The thing to keep in mind is when you initialise a module the config part will be run automatically, you can use this to either test directly or help set up a test.

**Option 1 - Using a fake module to setup**

```js
  describe('config sets $httpProvider interceptor', function () {
    var $httpProvider;

    beforeEach(function () {
      // First we initialise a random module, we will get $httpProvider
      // from it and then use that to spyOn.
      module(function (_$httpProvider_) {
        $httpProvider = _$httpProvider_;
        spyOn($httpProvider.interceptors, 'push');
      });

      // Now we initialise the app we want to test, $httpProvider will be
      // the spy from before. 
      module('myapp');
      inject();
    });

    it('should add to $httpProvider interceptors', function () {
      expect($httpProvider.interceptors.push)
        .toHaveBeenCalledWith('authInterceptorFactory');
    });
  });
```

**Option 2 - Using just your module**

```js
  describe('config sets $httpProvider interceptor', function () {
    var $httpProvider;

    beforeEach(function () {
      // First we initialise a your module, we will get $httpProvider
      // from it and then use that to assert on.
      module('myapp', function (_$httpProvider_) {
        $httpProvider = _$httpProvider_;
      });

      inject();
    });

    it('should add to $httpProvider interceptors', function () {
      expect($httpProvider.interceptors).toEqual(['authInterceptorFactory']);
    });
  });
```

Again, my recommendation (and the way I did it) is with option 1.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was never accepted ... it should be.